# Esimation of the tail dependence coefficient

Tags: r, data-visualization

Let (X,Y) be a random vector, we define the tail dependence coefficient between $X$ and $Y$  if it exists by 
$$\lambda=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X>u_n,Y>u_n)/P(X>u_n)$$
where $u_n$ is s.t $nP(X>u_n)\to\infty$.
It is known that 
$\hat{\lambda}_n=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^nI_{\{X_j>X_{(n-k)},Y_j>X_{(n-k)}\}}$ is an estimator of $\lambda$
where $I_{(.)}$ is an indicator function, $X_{(1)}>...>X_{(n)}$ are order statistics, $(X_j,Y_j)$ are $n$-iid realizations of $(X,Y)$ and $u_n$ is replaced with $X_{(n-k)}$.

**Question:** I want to plot $\hat{\lambda}_n$ vs $k$(the number of order statistic) using the example below.

**Example:** 
Consider the model $Y = \phi X + \sigma|Z|$, where $\phi=0.8\in(0,1)$, $\sigma=0.1$, $X$ is Pareto with
$\alpha=4$ and $Z$ is standard normal, independent of $X$.

Then $\lambda=(.8)^4$.

**Issue:** 
When I plot $\hat{\lambda}_n$ vs $k$ then the graph seems not to stabilize around $\lambda$ at all. I wonder if my R code is right or not.

```
n=1000;
## generating Pareto(4)
alpha=4;
U=runif(n);     
X=(1-U)^{(-1/alpha)} ;
## the model Y 
Z=rnorm(n);   
phi=0.8;
sigma=0.1;   ;   
Y=phi*X+sigma*abs(Z)  
## True lambda=(0.8)^4
lambda_hat=c();
lambda_hat=sapply(1:(n-1), FUN = function(i,min.=pmin(X,Y),Xsort=sort(X)) length(min.[min.>Xsort[n-i]])/i);
k=1:(n-1)

plot(k,lambda_hat,type = "l",lwd=2,col="blue",
     main="Tdc of X and Y",ylab="Estimates",xlab="Order statistics")
```

(Unfortunately i don't know how attach the graph).

Is this R code correct? If not, any help is much appreciated for the R code for $\hat{\lambda}_n$ and the graph thanks.

Hi @Glen_b, I accidentally created the second one but I already merged it, sorry about that.

@whuber, the value $\lambda=(0.8)^4$ is not related to $\sigma$ but $\phi\in(0,1)$ (which i forgot to specify) and $\alpha>0$. Indeed,

Note first that $Y\sim \phi X$, when $X$ is large (the random effect of $Z$ is negligible), hence, using the definition of The TDC above, we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}P(X>u_n,Y>u_n)/P(X>u_n)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}P(X>u_n,X>\phi^{-1}u_n)/P(X>u_n)\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}P(X>\phi^{-1}u_n)/P(X>u_n)&=(\phi^{-1})^{-\alpha}=\phi^{\alpha}=(0.8)^4.
\end{align}
the last line follows from the fact that $X$ is regularly varying with index $\alpha$ i.e. $\lim_{x\to \infty}P(X>xt)/P(X>x)=t^{-\alpha}$ for all $t>0$ .

"I am very new here, I can't even reply to your comments below, i have to reedit the post in order to do so." thanks.

Comment: What happens when you make `sigma` really, really small?  Indeed, what is the basis for supposing $\lambda=0.8^4$ exactly?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, $\lambda=(0.8)^4$ is not chosen at random rather it is obtained by evaluating the tail dependence coefficient defined above. By playing with $\phi$, $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ only the shape the curve changes. I gave this example just to test the performance of the estimator, one can replace it with this trivial example: $X$, $Y$ both iid Pareto($\alpha=4$), then the tail dep. coef. in this case is $\lambda=0$. I was also thinking that it may due to the fact that the estimator is very unstable.

Comment: Please [merge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts, so you can edit your post and comment in it.

Comment: I don't get $(0.8)^4$. I can produce that answer only by setting  `sigma <- 0` in the code. Nonzero values of `sigma` ought to increase $\lambda$.  If you want to experiment, then I warmly recommend subsampling your series of `lambda_hat`.  You don't need to compute every element in it--you only need a dozen or so, situated at indexes `k` that vary approximately geometrically. That will greatly speed things up.

Comment: Re the edit: In the code, $Y$ is equal to $\phi X$  *plus random noise with variance proportional to $\sigma^2$* (and with nonzero expectation!).  Your argument only shows why the plot should stabilize around $\phi^\alpha$ when $\sigma=0$.  It should *not* stabilize around that value for the appreciably large value of $0.1$ specified in the code.